# Is there a way to open/import an SVG file with Photoshop CS2 or CS3?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, svg

Title pretty much says it all... Is there a way to open/import an SVG file with Photoshop CS2 or CS3? I am on Mac OS X but cross platform solutions are preferred. Illustrator can open SVG files, so I find it odd that Photoshop cannot. I understand Illustrator is vector based, but Photoshop has limited vector capabilities also...

Answer (score 21):

You can open it in Inkscape (it's free, [inkscape.org](http://www.inkscape.org)) and export as PNG from there, with the size you prefer.

Comment: Thanks... I'm aware of that, I was just wondering if there's any way to open them directly in Photoshop.

Answer (score 5):

Adobe lost all interest in SVG when they bought Flash. Your best bet is to open it in Illustrator and convert it to something else that Photoshop can swallow.

Answer (score 3):

To use SVG images in Photoshop CS3 try out "SVG Kit for Adobe Creative Suite" from [svg.scand.com](http://svg.scand.com/) and that is the whole story!

Comment: For others' information, SVG Kit is a commercial plug-in which is only available free for a trial period.

Comment: Just a heads up: this website has a Trustworthiness rating of "Unsatisfactory" on [Web of Trust](https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/svg.scand.com), but no user reviews are listed.

Comment: Plus I've tried the trial for latest version, 2.0.2, for Mac, and it does not seem to be updated to work for Creative Cloud 2014. Nothing happens in my Photoshop CC 2014, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, SVG Kit for Adobe Creative Suite just for Photoshop/Elements is $100!  Adobe CS5 still won't open these files.  The best option for now is downloading [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) (free) and exporting it in a different format.

Answer (score 2):

SVG Kit for Adobe Creative Suite has a free trial anyway, so why not to try? Besides, it supports CS5.5, CS5, CS4 and CS3 and you don`t need to convert SVG to other formats.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GIMP to open and rasterize the SVG then save as a PSD. Gimp can also have the paths imported but I'm not sure how to save those to retain the vector graphics in photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

I always just place [ctrl+shft+p] it in Illustrator then copy and paste into photoshop as a smart object. Its quick and dirty but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about CS2 or CS3, but Photoshop CC 2015.1 now supports opening and importing static SVG files.

Answer (score 0):

Also, GIMP (free and open source) can open those. you could then export it or even copy-paste as rasterized @ resolution of your choice.

Comment: Needs converted to a comment.